# python pandas get accuracy of series

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

one last question for today:)
I have created crosstab from a df. this crosstab is apparently a series object. 
instead of printing the entire crosstab, in need one aggregated value showing the accuracy of that grid.
e.g. all correct predicted values vs. the total amount of data:

(31+48)/(31+43+33+48) = 0,509

```
Prediction  ZV
-1          -1    31
             1    43
 1          -1    33
             1    48
```

I found some samples, but none of them had a crosstab as an input...
thanks! E!

Comment: Are you sure `31+48` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes :) prediction is 1 and result is also 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first filter all values where index values in levels are same and then divide by sum:

```
print (s[s.index.get_level_values('Prediction') == s.index.get_level_values('ZV')])
Prediction  ZV
-1          -1    31
 1           1    48
Name: val, dtype: int64


s1 = s[s.index.get_level_values('Prediction')==s.index.get_level_values('ZV')].sum()/s.sum()
print (s1)
0.5096774193548387
```

Comment: Sorry, now i think it is typo. Nice day!